# MockRestServiceServer how to verify only request path exlcuding query string

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, mockrestserviceserver

I have a `@Component` DataClientImpl that calls a REST API using `RestTemplate`. The API endpoint has query params, which are passed when calling `RestTemplate`.
There is a `@RestClientTest` Test class `DataApiClientImplTest` testing the `DataClientImpl`, mocking the REST calls using `MockRestServiceServer`.

In the test method I want to verify that the correct endpoint path and query params (name particularly) are used in API call.
Using `MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo()` and `MockRestRequestMatchers.queryParam()` methods to verify.

The `MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo()` fails when the test is run. It appears to compare the actual url include query string with expected url without query string (that is passed to `MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo()` method.

In the pom, I am using

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

Code below.

```
@RestClientTest(DataApiClientImpl.class)
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
class DataApiClientImplTest {

    private static final String OBJECT_ID_URI = "http://localhost:8080/testBucketId/objects/test-obj-id";

    @Autowired
    private DataApiClientImpl dataApiClientImpl;

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer;

    @Test
    void testApiCall() {
        mockRestServiceServer.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(OBJECT_ID_URI))
                .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.queryParam("keyid", CoreMatchers.anything()))
                .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.queryParam("token", CoreMatchers.anything()))
                .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess("dummy", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        String response = dataApiClientImpl.getItem("asdf12345", "test-obj-id");

        Assertions.assertThat(response).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

The error is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected request expected:<http://localhost:8080/testBucketId/objects/test-obj-id> but was:<http://localhost:8080/testBucketId/objects/test-obj-id?token=asdf12345&keyid=testKeyId>
Expected :http://localhost:8080/testBucketId/objects/test-obj-id
Actual   :http://localhost:8080/testBucketId/objects/test-obj-id?token=asdf12345&keyid=testKeyId
```

I can pass in a Matcher instead to `requestTo()` method. But then what is the use of `MockRestRequestMatchers.queryParam()` method, when the whole url with query params has to be verified using Matcher.

One option is to use startsWith Matcher `MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(CoreMatchers.startsWith(OBJECT_ID_URI))`. But it is not same as exact match verification.

Tried with other overloaded versions of `MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo()` method. They all behave same.

Is there other better way to do exact endpoint path only match.

I did not include the test subject class code `DataClientImpl` as I thought it is out of scope of the problem, but I can add here if need.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this thread. The answer is very simple, but adding more details of my interesting findings that might be helpful to others.

**TL;DR answer:**
Use `mockRestServiceServer.expect(request -> assertEquals(OBJECT_ID_URI, request.getURI().getPath()))`

**Interesting Findings:**
It appears that, it is by design the `MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(String uri)` matches against the uri including query string. Below is the implementation extract of this method,

```
    public static RequestMatcher requestTo(String expectedUri) {
        Assert.notNull(expectedUri, "'uri' must not be null");
        return request -> assertEquals("Request URI", expectedUri, request.getURI().toString());
    }
```

What I mean by design is, the `java.net.URI` by definition is implementation of RFC 2396 and RFC 2732. Below is the extract from `java.net.URI` javadoc

> Represents a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) reference. Aside from
> some minor deviations noted below, an instance of this class
> represents a URI reference as defined by RFC 2396: Uniform Resource
> Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax, amended by RFC 2732: Format for
> Literal IPv6 Addresses in URLs.

I have not read the RFCs completely, but further the javadoc mentions under **URI syntax and components**

> A hierarchical URI is subject to further parsing according to the
> syntax
>
> [scheme:][//authority][path][?query][#fragment]

which indicates the URI is not just the request path, rather includes all these parts.
Therefore the `RequestMatcher` returned by `RequestMatchers.requestTo(String uri)` method that asserts as below

```
assertEquals("Request URI", expectedUri, request.getURI().toString())
```

compares actual URI including query string against expected uri. When expected uri string is path only without query string and the actual request contains query parameters, the assert fails.

So, my intention to match only the request path in `expect()` method, as the query parameters are asserted with subsequent `andExpect()` methods can be implemented as below

```
mockRestServiceServer.expect(request -> assertEquals(OBJECT_ID_URI, request.getURI().getPath()))
```

Using `java.net.URI#getPath()` method, that gives only the path part of the actual URI.

Another important point here is, the `RequestMatcher` is a Functional Interface with method

```
void match(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException, AssertionError;
```

A lambda expression can be passed to `expect()` method that takes `ClientHttpRequest` as argument and returns nothing (technically `void`).

The test method in complete is below and works as expected

```
    @Test
    void testApiCall() {
        mockRestServiceServer.expect(request -> assertEquals(OBJECT_ID_URI, request.getURI().getPath()))
                .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.queryParam("keyid", CoreMatchers.anything()))
                .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.queryParam("token", CoreMatchers.anything()))
                .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess("dummy", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        String response = dataApiClientImpl.getItem("asdf12345", "test-obj-id");

        Assertions.assertThat(response).isNotNull();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similiar issue recently and did not find any solution with built in matchers/methods. I ended up writing my own Matcher implementation, which looked something like this:

```
public class RequestPathMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    private final String expectedRequestPath;

    public static RequestPathMatcher of(String expectedRequestPath) {
        return new RequestContainsUriMatcher(expectedRequestPath);
    }

    private RequestPathMatcher(String expectedRequestPath) {
        this.expectedRequestPath = expectedRequestPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void match(ClientHttpRequest clientHttpRequest) throws AssertionError {
        final var actualRequestPath = clientHttpRequest.getURI().toString();
        var matchResult = false;
        // your match logic here
        assertTrue(matchResult , String.format("Expected %s to have request path%s", actualRequestPath, expectedRequestPath));
    }
}
```

You can the use it like this:

```
 mockServer
      .expect(RequestPathMatcher.of(requestPath))
      .andRespond(...)
```

Comment: @madhav-turangi: any feedback?

Comment: The actual problem is with `getURI().toString()` method. The  `MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo()` pretty much does the same.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that you can implement arbitrary logic inside the overriden `match` method, whatever you need.

Comment: I understand the point. I replied to usage of `getURI().toString()` in your answer. Misunderstanding the matcher given by  `MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo()` was the root of the problem, mainly with URI.  If using Java 8 and above, a lambda does the job, which I discovered and added more details below. Thanks for your participation.